# multiple definition with safe guard

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

#include "cstdint"

namespace Header {
    namespace Header2 {
        enum { s1, s2, s3 };
    }
    struct S {
        uint32_t m_index;
        S(uint32_t index) : m_index(index) {}
    };

    S s1(Header2::s1);
}
#endif
```

template.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_
#define CLASS_H_

#include "header.h"
#include "iostream"

template <class T>
class Class {
public:
    Class() {};
    void doSomething();
};

template <class T>
void Class<T>::doSomething() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

template.cpp

```
#include "template.h"
```

body.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "header.h"
#include "template.h"

class A {
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Header::s1.m_index << std::endl;
    Class<A> c;
    c.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

> $ g++ -Wall body.cpp template.cpp -o body -O3 -std=c++0x

```
/tmp/ccUYtE0g.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Header::s1'
/tmp/cca2YIRL.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought the safe guard `#ifndef CLASS_H_` would prevent duplicate inclusion. But it seems not.  Probably I miss something there?

Comment: It doesn't protect against different translation units including it and defining the same variable twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include guards protect against compiler errors caused by a header being included twice into the same source file. They do **not** protect against linker errors caused by two source files both defining the same object (often by means of including a header that contains said definition).

In order to avoid this latter kind of errors, do not define an object in a header file. Declare it in a header, define it in exactly one source. Like this:

```
// .h file
extern S s1;

// source file
Header::S Header::s1(Header::Header2::s1);
```

Comment: What's your take on the alternative -- static variable instead?  Since it also means "only one".  Also using static variable will allow to be used as a template parameter.

Comment: If you define a static variable in a header file, each source file that includes this header will get its own distinct instance of the variable  - they will **not** all share the same object. This may or may not be what you want - hard to tell since you've never explained the goal of the exercise.

Comment: Just trying to see whether there is a way to "let" the compiler know the exact value of a shared variable without a duplicate copy at compile time (not linking).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The compiler can read the exact value from the variable whenever it needs one, no special "letting" required. If you mean you want to let the compiler know the *initial* value, then it's not clear what the compiler is supposed to do with this information even if somehow available. In what way, do you believe, would such knowledge be helpful?

Comment: Actually I should specify s1 as const so that the compiler can try to optimize the code further as the value is constant and known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Include guards only stop the same header being included twice in the same translation unit (the same `.cpp` file, kind of). Of course, headers are *meant* to be included in multiple files. There are certain things that can and can't appear more than once across all translation units. One of those things is a namespace scoped variable definition.

To make the definition of `s1` only a declaration (which can appear in multiple translation units), you need to make it extern:

```
extern S s1;
```

But then you need to have a definition of it somewhere, so in a *single* `.cpp` file, you'll need to have:

```
S s1(Header2::s1);
```

Make sure they're in the appropriate namespaces.

Comment: The declaration with `extern` shouldn't contain an initializer.